# Which version of the Windows SDK do I need?

Tags: windows, sdk

I have a 64 bit Core 2 Duo processor but the 32 bit version of Vista. Also, I want to have the 64 bit libs and cross compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 32bit SDK and the 64 bit SDK as I think the latter has X compiler options.

Comment: Both? That's 2.8 GB of downloading!

Comment: I have a suggestion. To make good use of your 64bit C2D, you'd better re-install your OS to 64-bit. Full 64-bit gives you better use of memory spaces and you don't need to download the 32-bit SDK.

Comment: I found a MSDN blog saying you only need the x86 version... so that's what I think I will download.

Answer (score 1):

Your SDK doesn't know the CPU, it call the operating system functions.
So you only need the 32bits SDK